# Print 20 random numbers in range, check if odd or even

Tags: python, function, random, return-value

I've been killing myself with this assignment for the past week and I'm still baffled. I have to create a program that gets the user to input 2 numbers, arranges them in order of size, prints 20 random numbers within the range and also determines whether or not they are odd or even. Here's what I've got so far:

```
#Main function
import random
def main():
    first = int(input("Enter first integer: "))
    second = int(input("Enter second integer: "))
    def sortnums(first, second):
        if first > second:
            return second, first
        else:
            return first, second
        MIN, MAX = sortnums(first, second)

    for x in range(20):
        random = random.randrange(MIN, MAX)
        if random%2 == 0:
            print ("The random number", random ,"is even.")
        elif random%2 != 0:
            print ("The random number", random ,"is odd.")
    return random

main()
```

I'm not just lazily asking for a solution, I've genuinely exhausted my efforts on this one and even contacted my lab tutor for additional advice but I'm still clueless as to why it's not working.
Thanks.

Comment: For reference, instead of sortnums you could simply call the builtin `sorted`.

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
random = random.randrange(MIN, MAX)
```

You've shadowed the `random` module with a number. You should pick a different variable name, like `random_number` so subsequent calls to `random.randrange` don't error:

```
for x in range(20):
    random_number= random.randrange(MIN, MAX)
    if random_number % 2 == 0:
        print ("The random number", random_number, "is even.")
    elif random_number % 2 != 0:
        print ("The random number", random_number, "is odd.")
return random_number
```

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest oversight is probably shadowing the `random` you imported with the first random number you select. After this, you program would fail the second time through the loop when it tries to look up the `randrange` attribute on an int.

There's already a nice builtin way to sort numbers

```
def sortnums(first, second):
    return sorted([first, second])
```

More simply, using tuple unpacking

```
import random
def main():
    first = int(input("Enter first integer: "))
    second = int(input("Enter second integer: "))
    for x in range(20):
        num = random.randrange(*sorted([first, second]))
        if num%2 == 0:
            print ("The random number", num ,"is even.")
        else:
            print ("The random number", num ,"is odd.")
    return

main()
```

You can remove repetition from the print functions like this

```
import random
def main():
    first = int(input("Enter first integer: "))
    second = int(input("Enter second integer: "))
    for x in range(20):
        num = random.randrange(*sorted([first, second]))
        print("The random number", num ,"is", "odd." if num%2 else "even.")
    return

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

A few problems with your code.  But you are pretty close.  I think you may just have issues with understanding how your program is executed.  The "main()" function call at the bottom is the first code execution point.  The user prompts are collecting the user data just fine, but then you just define two functions and never actually call them.  Additionally, you use the word "random" as a variable name but this is also being used as the namespace for the random library.  Below is a fixed up version...

```
import random

def main():
    first = int(input("Enter first integer: "))
    second = int(input("Enter second integer: "))
    MIN, MAX = sortnums(first, second)

    for x in range(20):
        randNum = random.randrange(MIN, MAX)
        if randNum%2 == 0:
            print ("The random number", randNum ,"is even.")
        elif randNum%2 != 0:
            print ("The random number", randNum ,"is odd.")

def sortnums(first, second):
    if first > second:
        return second, first
    else:
        return first, second

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import random

min_input = int(input("Enter first integer: "))
max_input = int(input("Enter second integer: "))

if max_input<min_input:
    min_input, max_input=max_input, min_input

for i in range(20):
    rnd=random.randrange(min_input, max_input)    
    print 'The random number {} is {}.'.format(rnd, ('even', 'odd')[rnd%2])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take the `def sortnums` outside of the main function:

```
import random

def sortnums(first, second):
    if first > second:
        return second, first
    else:
        return first, second
```

Then the MIN, MAX assignment seems to have wrong indentation...
and you re-assign random (the module) with a value. Change it to something
like r or number.

```
def main():
   first = int(input("Enter first integer: "))
   second = int(input("Enter second integer: "))

   MIN, MAX = sortnums(first, second)

   for x in range(20):
       r = random.randrange(MIN, MAX)

       if r%2 == 0:
           print ("The random number", r ,"is even.")
       elif r%2 != 0:
           print ("The random number", r ,"is odd.")
    return r

main()
```